# Obtaining the array Class of a component type

Tags: java, arrays

If I have an instance of `Class`, is there a way of obtaining a `Class` instance for its array type? What I'm essentially asking for is the equivalent of a method `getArrayType` which is the inverse of the `getComponentType()` method, such that:

```
array.getClass().getComponentType().getArrayType() == array.getClass()
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind is:

```
java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(componentType, 0).getClass();
```

But it creates an unnecessary instance.

Btw, this appears to work:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("[L" + componentType.getName() + ";");
```

Here is test. It prints `true`:

```
Integer[] ar = new Integer[1];
Class componentType = ar.getClass().getComponentType();
Class clazz = Class.forName("[L" + componentType.getName() + ";");

System.out.println(clazz == ar.getClass());
```

[The documentation of `Class#getName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) defines strictly the format of array class names:

> If this class object represents a class of arrays, then the internal form of the name consists of the name of the element type preceded by one or more '[' characters representing the depth of the array nesting.

The `Class.forName(..)` approach won't directly work for primitives though - for them you'd have to create a mapping between the name (`int`) and the array shorthand - (`I`)

Comment: The first version (using `Array.newInstance(...).getClass()`) *does* work for primitives.

Comment: This is very useful, thanks. For my purposes, I don't need to handle primitives so either approach is useable.

Comment: The `Class.forName()` approach also produces temporary objects for the string concatenation (e.g. new StringBuilder().append("[L").append(componentType.getName()).append(";").toString()).  So I imagine the first approach produces fewer allocations, even with the unnecessary one.

Comment: You may want to use Class.forName("[L" + componentType.getName() + ";", false, componentType.getClassLoader())

Comment: Yes, the class loader is important here.

Comment: Can anyone here explain me what does this mean? Class<T[]> arrayClass = (Class<T[]>) Class.forName("[L" + anyClazz.getName() + ";");

Comment: As @ɲeuroburɳ said, the `Class.forName(…)` approach creates even more temporary objects, is more expensive (the longer the class name, the more expensive), further, the zero-sized array has much better chances of getting removed by the optimizer, but even worse, the `Class.forName(…)` approach not only doesn’t work for primitive types, it also doesn’t work for array types (when trying to get a multi-dimensional array type). While `Array.newInstance(componentType, 0).getClass()` just does the job. With Java 12+, you can just use `componentType.arrayType()`; guess what it does under the hood…

Answer (score 16):

Actually due to `ClassLoader`, primitives and multi-dimensional arrays, the answer is a little more complex:

```java
public static Class<?> getArrayClass(Class<?> componentType) throws ClassNotFoundException{
    ClassLoader classLoader = componentType.getClassLoader();
    String name;
    if(componentType.isArray()){
        // just add a leading "["
        name = "["+componentType.getName();
    }else if(componentType == boolean.class){
        name = "[Z";
    }else if(componentType == byte.class){
        name = "[B";
    }else if(componentType == char.class){
        name = "[C";
    }else if(componentType == double.class){
        name = "[D";
    }else if(componentType == float.class){
        name = "[F";
    }else if(componentType == int.class){
        name = "[I";
    }else if(componentType == long.class){
        name = "[J";
    }else if(componentType == short.class){
        name = "[S";
    }else{
        // must be an object non-array class
        name = "[L"+componentType.getName()+";";
    }
    return classLoader != null ? classLoader.loadClass(name) : Class.forName(name);
}
```

Comment: In the last line, you could also use the forName method with class loader parameter (which also works for `null`, thus avoiding the case distinction).

Comment: The last line did not work for me, but forName with the classloader as parameter did.

Answer (score 9):

You can do the following

```
array.getClass() == 
    Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), 0).getClass()
```

Usually, you don't need to know the type, you just want to create the array.

Answer (score 4):

Java 12 introduced [`arrayType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#arrayType())

```
String.class.arrayType() == String[].class;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible refactoring is to use a generic superclass and pass in two class objects to the constructor.

```
protected AbstractMetaProperty(Class<T> valueClass, Class<T[]> valueArrayClass) {
  this.valueClass = valueClass;
  this.valueArrayClass = valueArrayClass;
}
```

Then in subclasses:

```
public IntegerClass() {
  super(Integer.class, Integer[].class);
}
```

Then in the abstract class you can use `valueClass.cast(x)`, `valueArrayClass.isInstance(x)` etc.