# Obtaining Class<T[]> without creating an array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Given a `Class<T>` is there any way to get a `Class<T[]>` without first creating an array via `Array.newInstance`?  Even that doesn't really do quite what I want because `Array.newInstance` would return something of type `Object`, so I'd still be left doing an unchecked cast.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the question: you do have an instance of some generic class, the generic specified by `T`. Now you want to get a new instance of the generic class where the generic is specified by `T[]`? Like `List<String>` becomes `List<String[]>`?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901128/obtaining-the-array-class-of-a-component-type?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Use [Class.forName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Class<?> arrayofTsClass = Class.forName("[L" + tClass.getName() + ";");
```

Comment: I guess that works, but I'd still need to do an unsafe cast, because Class.forName returns a Class<?>.  I suppose I should clarify, the whole reason I want to obtain a Class<T[]> is to use its cast method, so if I have to do a unsafe cast to get one to begin with, there really isn't much point.

Comment: Ah, I understand a little better now.  Could you post some of the code as an example - that would help.  For example, I can't imagine why you wouldn't just cast it yourself (that's what those `Class` methods are for, the implementation of casts, etc).

Comment: @user1063042 I don't think you can do this without an *unchecked* cast, which is not necessarily an *unsafe* cast. It's just a compiler warning, because while it may indicate a code problem, it may also be perfectly "safe".