# How can I get an element type class from an array type class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, generics

Can I get `Class<T>` from `Class<T[]>`?

```
public static <T> void doSometing(final Class<T[]> arrayType) {

    final Class<T> elementType; // = @@?
}
```

Or, can I get `Class<T[]>` from `Class<T>`?

Comment: Can you please explain the use case for this

Comment: I rolled back your update since it ended up taking the form of a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Class.getComponentType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType%28%29), although there's no way for that method to give you generic type safety, so you'll need to do an unchecked cast to get a `Class<T>`:

```
public static <T> void doSomething(final Class<T[]> arrayType) {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final Class<T> componentType = (Class<T>)arrayType.getComponentType();

    //etc.
}
```

For the reverse, see this question: [Obtaining the array Class of a component type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901128/obtaining-the-array-class-of-a-component-type)

Comment: Can you please take a look at this following question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204788/two-methods-for-creating-a-generic-array

Comment: @JinKwon Sorry I didn't see that sooner. Looks like it's been answered pretty well.