# Two methods for creating generic arrays

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I've learned following two methods for creating generic arrays.

One is

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> T[] array1(final Class<T> elementType, final int size) {

    return (T[]) Array.newInstance(elementType, size);
}
```

And the other is

```java
static <T> T[] array2(final Class<T[]> arrayType, final int size) {

    return arrayType.cast(Array.newInstance(arrayType.getComponentType(), size));
}
```

Which is better? Are they same (internally)? Is any case actually wrong?

Comment: I think the first approach is better

Comment: can someone explain the second approach? what is it doing?

Comment: Following Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226379/how-to-create-generic-primitive-arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Behind the scenes, the two do effectively the same thing, except that in option 1 you're passing in `T`'s class object and in option 2 you're passing in `T[]`'s class object.

I prefer option 1 because it's shorter and easier to read. Then again, it's the same as `Array.newInstance` with a cast added, so I'm not sure that your method adds a lot of value. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Note that the first one is not type-safe. For example, the following causes a ClassCastException:

```
array1(int.class, 5);
```

Comment: Checked and confirmed. Both methods don't event compile for primitive types.

Comment: @JinKwon: No, the first one compiles and throws an exception. The second one doesn't compile, and is type-safe.

Comment: doesn't compile if assigned to an `int[]` variable

Answer (score 0):

Another (better) way to create generic arrays

```
@SafeVarargs
static <E> E[] newArray(int length, E... array)
{
    return Arrays.copyOf(array, length);
}


Integer[] ints = newArray(10);

String[] strings = newArray(10);
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if the caller itself is in generic scope and doesn't resolve `T` to a concrete type.

Comment: only because of erasure:) and the same problem exists for array1/array2() too.

Comment: It doesn't because they use a `Class` type token and reflection to work around erasure.