# How to create generic primitive arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, primitive

This is a following question coming from [Two methods for creating generic arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204788/two-methods-for-creating-generic-arrays).

With given two methods,

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> T[] array1(final Class<T> elementType, final int size) {

    return (T[]) Array.newInstance(elementType, size);
}
```

```java
static <T> T[] array2(final Class<T[]> arrayType, final int size) {

    return arrayType.cast(Array.newInstance(arrayType.getComponentType(), size));
}
```

Both methods work fine for Object type.

```
final Integer[] objectArray1 = array1(Integer.class, 0);
final Integer[] objectArray2 = array2(Integer[].class, 0);
```

When it comes to primitives, both invocation don't compile.

```java
// array1
final int[] primitiveArray1 = array1(int.class, 0);
```

```
GenericArray.java:12: error: incompatible types
        final int[] primitiveArray1 = array1(int.class, 0);
                                            ^
  required: int[]
  found:    Integer[]
1 error
```

```java
// array2
final int[] primitiveArray2 = array2(int[].class, 0);
```

```
GenericArray.java:13: error: method array2 in class GenericArray cannot be applied to given types;
        final int[] primitiveArray2 = array2(int[].class, 0);
                                      ^
  required: Class<T[]>,int
  found: Class<int[]>,int
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: int
    bound(s): Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>array2(Class<T[]>,int)
1 error
```

How can I do with primitive types?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java how to: Generic Array creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @Code-Guru: I don't see it. They seem to be asking very different things.

Comment: @ruakh I should have looked more closely ;-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead

```
static <A> A array3(final Class<A> arrayType, final int size) 
{    impl omitted... }

final int[] primitiveArray3 = array3(int[].class, 0);
```

Comment: Can someone edit this post to provide the "impl omitted"? I'm not getting what should be there.

Answer (score 4):

Primitives are incompatible with generics; for example, you can't create a `List<int>`, and the type of `int.class` is `Class<Integer>` rather than `Class<int>`. So what you describe is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal way:

```
int[] foo = (int[])Array.newInstance(int.class, 5);
```

As ruakh mentioned, you cannot make something work generically for primitive types, so you're gonna have to cast the result somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use primitives with generics. On the other hand, you can use `Integer[]` in place of `int[]` and rely on auto(un)boxing to convert between `int` and `Integer` when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use primitives with generics, only `Objects`; however, you can use their wrappers: `Integer`, `Character`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works and creates int[]:

```
final Object instance = Array.newInstance(Integer.TYPE, 0);
```