# How to get the class associated to an array type?

Tags: java, arrays, class, new-operator

Does anyone know a better way to write the following statement:

```
example.mySpecialMethod(new MySpecialClass[0].getClass())
```

I need the array type, but I dont know if there is a better solution. At the moment this example works for me, but perhaps someone knows a better way to do the same without the `new` keyword.

Comment: Why not `MySpecialClass.class` ? If `mySpecialMethod()` takes a `Class` as parameter, then it makes no sense instantiating an array.

Comment: the method expects 'Class<? extends MySpecialClass[]> c' as param

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The class of `new MySpecialClass[0]` is `MySpecialClass[].class` so you can use:

```
example.mySpecialMethod(MySpecialClass[].class)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would be the best solution if your component type wasn't known at compile time? I can't think of a better way than `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance( componentClass, 0 ).getClass()`

Comment: @biziclop my code is equivalent to the original. But if you need the actual class of some object then you need a reference to that object.

Comment: I know, it just occurred to me as a complete aside. Given a class object of an array, you can simply call `getComponentType()` to get the component class. But the reverse seems to be far more complicated.

Comment: @biziclop: Your question was already answered: [Obtaining the array Class of a component type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901128/obtaining-the-array-class-of-a-component-type).