# Generic method passing class as a parameter

Tags: java, generics

How to generify this method? I'm trying to receive a class in my parameter and return a object from that class.

However, Java says that "any.class" int the return is unknown.

Am I doing something wrong with generics? How can I generify this method to receive a ResponseEntity and a Class and then return a Object from that class?

```
public static <T> T parseToJson(Class<T> any, ResponseEntity responseEntity) {
    try {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseEntity.getBody().toString(), any.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

One more doubt: If I want to return a array of objects, I used to do

```
 return Arrays.asList(new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseEntity.getBody().toString(), ResponseListCameras[].class));
```

but I'm trying to do

```
return Arrays.asList(new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseEntity.getBody().toString(), any[]));
```

and it seems to expect an expression. What can I do?

Comment: `any` is already a class. You don't need `.class` to get a class from it.

Comment: is the method signature correct?

Comment: Looks all good to me

Comment: BTW, if in doubt, you can always look at the method signature for ObjectMapper.readValue()

Comment: `any` is already a `Class`, but all `Class`es are `Object`s too, so you can call `any.getClass()`. But that would then simply be `Class.class`.

Comment: Edited my post to include the array question

Answer (score 3):

1. Change `any.class` to `any` since `any` is already a `Class<T>` instance.
2. Rethrow the exception unless you want to return something default after the `try-catch` statement.

Otherwise, you will get 2 compilation errors.

3. Don't use raw types. `ResponseEntity` has a type parameter.

Comment: What should I do with ResponseEntity?

Comment: Edited my post to include the array question

Comment: @FearX you can't make `any[]` out of `any`, you should pass an array-based class instead (e.g. `parseToJson(ResponseListCameras[].class, actualResponseEntity)`)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yes, I'm writing another method. That question is about(i don't know how it is called in engish) overcharging that method to accept an array, too

Comment: @AndrewTobilko i'll pass an any[] in this case

Comment: @FearX you probably meant "overloading". The thing is you aren't overloading anything: the method remains the same except for the type. And I don't know any a nice way to turn `any` into `any[]`

Comment: @FearX have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901128/obtaining-the-array-class-of-a-component-type

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yes, overloading. Thank you for that. I think I found a nice way, can you say what you think about it? It's the "obi-wan" answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects

Comment: @FearX yes, it might work. But, for the second method, you need to change its name. You can't have 2 methods with the same signature and name.

Comment: Yeah, sure. That makes perfect sense to me

Answer (score 0):

Here you pass a `String` provided from `getBody().toString()` to deserialize the json.
The approach looks weird because `ResponseEntity` is a generic class and that `ResponseEntity.getBody()` returns an instance of the generic.
So you should not even use directly Jackson here.

`ResponseEntity` is typed as long as you use it correctly.

For example :

```
ResponseEntity<Foo> responseEntityFoo = template.getForEntity("/getAnUrl...", Foo.class);
Foo foo = responseEntityFoo.getBody();
```

So you should have the JSON deserialized just like that.

Comment: Fantastic, @davidxxx. But how should I return an List without using directly Jackson?

Comment: I removed the second part. That is helpless. If you want to deserialize it, it means that your service returns a JSON in its body. Just use it. If you receive a JSON array , just specify it in your invocation : `ResponseEntity<Foo[]> responseEntities = template.getForEntity("url...", Foo[].class);
List<Foo> = Arrays.asList(responseEntities.getBody());`

Comment: Arrays.asList is dropping ClassCastException to me

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Comment: In fact, all "getBody()" are dropping the same exception

Comment: do you have any idea about this exception?

Comment: No Idea, really.