# Kotlin Reified lost type information in certain cases

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I came up with a strange behaviour with Kotlin reified. Following is an example test class.

```
data class User(var name: String = "name", var age: Int = 0)

    private val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
    private val userArray: String = """[{"name":"Alice","age":1},{"name":"Bob","age":2}]"""
    private val user: String = """{"name":"Alice","age":1}"""

    private inline fun <reified V> getUserObjects(jsonString: String): List<V> = objectMapper
        .readValue(jsonString, Array<V>::class.java).toList()

    private inline fun <reified V> getUserObject(jsonString: String): V = objectMapper
        .readValue(jsonString, V::class.java)
   
    @Test
    fun single_object_success() {
        val actual: User = getUserObject(user)
        Assertions.assertEquals("Alice", (actual as User).name)
    }

    @Test
    fun object_list_error() {
        val actual: List<User> = getUserObjects(userArray)
        Assertions.assertEquals("Alice", (actual.first() as User).name)
        // java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class MockTests$User
    }
```

While the first test case passes as expected the second test case fails with the above mentioned exception. By looking at the java decompiled code (below) it seems reified is incapable of populating the type in the first inline function (getUserObjects).

```
   @Test
   public final void single_object_success() {
      String jsonString$iv = this.user;
      int $i$f$getUserObject = false;
      User actual = (User)access$getObjectMapper$p(this).readValue(jsonString$iv, User.class);
      if (actual == null) {
         throw new NullPointerException("null cannot be cast to non-null type MockTests.User");
      } else {
         Assertions.assertEquals("Alice", actual.getName());
      }
   }

   @Test
   public final void object_list_error() {
      String jsonString$iv = this.userArray;
      int $i$f$getUserObjects = false;
      Object var10000 = access$getObjectMapper$p(this).readValue(jsonString$iv, Object[].class);
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullExpressionValue(var10000, "objectMapper\n        .re…ng, Array<V>::class.java)");
      List actual = ArraysKt.toList((Object[])var10000);
      Object var10001 = CollectionsKt.first(actual);
      if (var10001 == null) {
         throw new NullPointerException("null cannot be cast to non-null type MockTests.User");
      } else {
         Assertions.assertEquals("Alice", ((User)var10001).getName());
      }
   }
```

Is this the default behaviour with Kotlin reified? If so can someone explain the rationale behind this?
Because myself and IntelliJ believe the Object array should be an User array.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a problem with Kotlin or `reified`, it's because Jackson is a Java library, and isn't Kotlin-aware. If you use a serialization library like `kotlinx.serialization`, you can do what you want easily. (You can do what you want with Jackson too, but it requires some more juggling of types.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the generated Java code shows an object[] class. Shouldn't it be User[] class?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And if you use `kotlinx.serialization`, that's what it will be. And again, you can do it with Jackson too, but not by using a reified parameter like this.

Comment: Oh, and you probably want to use a `List`, not an `Array`.

Comment: @Jorn That really has nothing to do with Jackson. Kotlin reified does **not** preserve array component types (at least on jvm platform), that's all. The problem to the question is already answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58628915/2678097). If you leave Jackson out of it, and just test that: `inline fun <reified V> printCType() = println(Array<V>::class.java.componentType)` you will see that it prints `class java.lang.Object`, whereas if you run `fun main() = println(Array<User>::class.java.componentType)`, then you will have `class User`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin. Trying to use reified types to parse Lists and Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627671/kotlin-trying-to-use-reified-types-to-parse-lists-and-arrays)